# How to get Facebook user's email using the Koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use FB Open Graph to let my app update a user's attribute. I have Koala installed and using facebook-omniauth for my authentication. Simply I would like query my database looking for a user that matches his fb id and if that user does not exist then I would like to update the user model's attributes with data from the facebook API. Also I'm using mongoid as oppose to active record for my database.

In my user model I have this method.

def facebook
 @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end

Within my controller I have these lines of code within one of my methods.

@user = User.where(facebook_uid: params[:auth_id])

```
if @user.empty?
      User.create(
       first_name: User.facebook.get_object("name"),
       last_name: User.facebook.get_object("email"),
       facebook_uid: params[:auth_id],
       facebook_oauth_token: params[:auth_token])
    else
      User.update_attributes(
        facebook_oauth_token: params[:auth_token]
    end
```

User.facebook.get_object("email") does not return me a user's email when I play around in my console. Does anybody have any idea how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: After much playing around in my console I was able to figure it out. The line of code to use to retrieve a user's email is:

User.facebook.get_object("me", :fields=>"email")["email"]

I'm sure there is an easier way to do it but this worked for me.

Comment: make sure that you have gotten the oauth token with `user_email` permission. then you become able to issue `@facebook.get_object user_id` which will return user info with user's email

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object('me', fields:'email')
```

Now `profile['email']` will get you the email of the user.

Comment: It used to be that get_object included email always - now sometimes facebook won't include that unless you include email in the fields list...

Comment: how get name AND email in same time?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
  facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  public_attributes = facebook.get_object("me")
```

if public_attributes does not return email, this means that the user has not authorized the email for your App. check that you add "email" scope to the OAuth authorization process. If you use devise, this is the config:

```
  config.omniauth :facebook,  "facebook_app_key",  "facebook_app_secret", {scope: "email"}
```

Comment: The question is specifically how to do it with Koala, not with omniauth.
To get the email you need first to request permission to the user via OAuth. You will get an OAuth access token which you can use to access to the Graph API and get the user email.

```Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret, callback_url).url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => "email")```